# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-06-04" (at offset 5)

Tags: java, android, android-date

I want to parse the date into a desired format but i am receiving an exception every time.
i know it is easy to implement but i am facing some problem don't know where exactly.:

```
Exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-06-04" (at offset 5)
```

Following is my code:

```
private String getconvertdate(String date) {
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = inputFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);
    return outputText;
}
```

**Input to method: 2014-06-04**

**Expected Output: 06-Jun-2014**

I have followed some Ref. from Stackoverflow.com, but still he problem persist.
Please Help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have no time part in your string:
and the Month has only two character 
replace

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

with

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem....

public String convertDateStringFormat(String strDate, String fromFormat, String toFormat){
       try{
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
          sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
          SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat.trim());
          return dateFormat2.format(sdf.parse(strDate));
       }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return "";
       }
}
```

Comment: but for month it always give me 'Jan' for MMM

Comment: Can you please let me know fromFormate and toFormate value your are passing to this function ?

Comment: fromFormate = dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm a
toFormate = MMM

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to tackle different input formats
Then catch the currently  unmanaged format exception (just a sample):

```
private String getconvertdate(String date) {
    System.out.println(date.length());
    DateFormat inputFormat = null;
            if(date.length() == 20)
                inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
    if(date.length() == 10)
        inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH) ;

    if(null == inputFormat)
        return "Format invalid";

    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = inputFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "Input Date invalid";
    }
    String outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);
    return outputText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using ::

```
SimpleDateFormat todaySdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

changed it to

```
SimpleDateFormat todaySdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

and it worked.. the extra M was the culprit !!