# Parse exception in Android

Tags: android, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I am using `SimpleDateFormat` class to parse date as follows :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

But, getting the Parse exception error as follows :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-09-16 10:21 AM" (at offset 16)
```

I have checked another format as a argument in `SimpleDateFormat` class is : 
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a" but, still same error is coming.

Is there any other datetime format I have to pass as a argument of `SimpleDateFormat` class ?

Comment: Maybe you don't have `:ss` in your sample input?

Comment: Yes, because I have used TimePicker for getting input.

Comment: Refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030767/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-2014-06-04-at-offset-5 see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have said in the above comments, you use a `TimePicker` for choosing a date  time and parse it. And you said that you also want the second. But apparently, `TimePicker` doesn't include the second. So how are you going to know what second the user wants? I guess 0. You can insert a string into the correct position to make it work. In you case you should insert ":00" in index 16. Just use a `StringBuilder`!

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("2015-09-16 10:21 AM");
builder.insert (16, ":00");
```

Comment: Without the `:ss` the seconds would default to 0. There should be no need to insert `:00` in the data and `:ss` in the pattern, unless the pattern is also used elsewhere with seconds input.

Comment: @headuck Well yes... you are right. But if you insert the string the seconds is not limited to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if your input has not second value ..

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
```

And if it has second value also then use this

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
```

otherwise above one

[For More detail....](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: If you input does not have second how could you parse the seconds?

Answer (score 1):

`TimePicker` widget doesn't provide year-month-day , it only provide hour and minutes

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

To get year-month-day you have to use `DatePicker` widget

Comment: If you are using TimePicker widget it will only provide time not year month and day use  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm a"); to get year month and day you have to use DatePicker

Comment: You are right, I am using DatePicker also and storing date value in Date field and using TimePicker to store time in Time field in database and combining both the values when i am retrieving it from database. Thanks for your efforts.